# How could I change the reset password VIEW that's been sent through email?

Tags: php, laravel, email, view, laravel-jetstream

I want to change the aspect of the html view that jetstream sends through an email to the user's email inbox for the user to reset the password.I cant seem to find the blade file. Does anyone knows where it might be? or how could i change this file? I wish i could upload an image but apparently im not popular enough in this platform xd

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```